# How to remove trailing comma for Python code formatter Ruff

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ruff

Before applying the ruff formatter

```
def method(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg10):
```

After applying the ruff formatter

```
def method(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3,
    ...,
    arg10,
)
```

Is there a way to configure the ruff formatter to remove the trailing comma next to arg10 by passing an argument to ruff.format.args?

```
"ruff.format.args": ["remove-trailing-comma"]
```

Comment: Nope. It's designed to be a drop-in replacement for Black and Black doesn't have that option either. I'm curious why you'd want it though. The whole point of using a formatter is that it can automatically do things like ensuring there are trailing commas.

Comment: In Python, trailing commas are generally considered good practice because they make diffs cleaner when adding or removing arguments. That's why formatters like `black` add them by default and don't provide an option to remove them.